# jboss eap 6.3 core bridge between two clusters

Tags: queue, jboss6.x, hornetq

I am trying to configure a core bridge between two jboss eap 6.3 applications clusters A and B. They are on the same subnet.

My Bridge Config on a node in **Cluster A**

```
<bridges>
    <bridge name="the-bridge">
        <queue-name>jms.queue.X</queue-name>
        <forwarding-address>jms.queue.XX</forwarding-address>
        <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group2"/>
        <user>user</user>
        <password>pass</password>
    </bridge>
</bridges>
```

the discovery group definition

```
<discovery-group name="dg-group2">
    <socket-binding>messaging-group2</socket-binding>
    <refresh-timeout>10000</refresh-timeout>
</discovery-group>
```

And the messaging group

```
<socket-binding name="messaging-group2" interface="all-interfaces" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9877}"/>
```

Then on **cluster B** node I have a broadcast group

```
<broadcast-group name="bg-group2">
    <socket-binding>messaging-group2</socket-binding>
    <broadcast-period>5000</broadcast-period>
    <connector-ref>netty</connector-ref>
</broadcast-group>
```

with

```
<socket-binding name="messaging-group2" interface="all-interfaces" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9877}"/>
```

My question is how can I create a bridge to pass messages on queue X in cluster A to queue XX in cluster B. I cannot achieve this am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? I would appreciate any examples and verification that this works. I can get a bridge working in this manner forwarding to another queue defined in cluster A but I want to discover the queue on Cluster B which I can't achieve.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also needed a connection factory.

```
<jms-connection-factories>
   <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactoryBridge">
     <discovery-group-ref discovery-group-name="dg-group2"/>
     <entries>
        <entry name="RemoteConnectionFactoryBridge"/>
        <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactoryBridge"/>
      </entries>
    </connection-factory>               
</jms-connection-factories>
```